# Does doctrine allow 2 models to use the same table

Tags: inheritance, doctrine

I have an abstract class User and 2 classes which inherit from it, namely BEUser and FEUser.
Information about all users (FEUser and BEUser) is stored in a single table.
Does Doctrine allows this kind of mapping? Any examples?

Also if doctrine supports it which object does the table class return (FEUser or BEUser)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. It's called "[simple](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/inheritance/en#simple)" or "[column aggregation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/inheritance/en#column-aggregation)" inheritance. Second one allows to store object type in database.